# can't make inference with my model using sahi

Tags: yolo, inference

I have finetuned Yolox on my custom dataset and want to use Slicing Aided Hyper Inference SAHI, but I can't
there are use cases for some pretrained models like

````
    model_type='mmdet',
    model_path=model_path,
    config_path=config_path,
    confidence_threshold=0.4,
    image_size=640,
    device="cpu", # or 'cuda:0'
)```

but I need to add my model weights and path and it is not of any model_type.
````